# How can I use third party (or self created) emoticons in Xcode for custom SMS app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sms, emoticons

I am using the open source AcaniChat to make a SMS app. But the main point of the app is to have a specific set of emoticons. After customising colours etc. for the frontend. I would like to include a custom set of emoticons for users to send to each other.

Anyone who wants to use the emoticons will obviously have to download the app as I know I can't embed the custom emoticons to iOS' unicode emoticons, that is why I'm having a separate SMS app for the whole thing.

So to be clear. I do not want to use iOS' emoticons in my app. I want to use my own, original ones (like in the 'Viber' app)

How do I go about doing this? Is there a open source add-on or something I can use in xcode?

Thank you.

Comment: have you found anything on this?